# SearchView and ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I've inserted a search capability in my actionBar.  I can see the search icon, but am unable to show the search dialog box in the actionBar.  I've tried modifying the v14 abs_themes file as recommended by others with no luck.  My xml menu is as follows:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="search sites"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    android:actionViewClass="com.ActionbarSherlock.widget.SearchView" >
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:icon="@drawable/images_on"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Grid">
</item>
```

In onCreateOptionsMenu, I've inserted:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    this.menu = menu;

    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.sites_actionbar, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();


    if (searchView != null) {

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    }
```

I keep getting following ClassNotFoundException:

```
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111): Cannot instantiate class: com.ActionbarSherlock.widget.SearchView
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ActionbarSherlock.widget.SearchView" on path: /data/app/com.mcgarrybowen.CPC-1.apk
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:486)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:447)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:468)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:190)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.mcgarrybowen.CPC.SiteCategoryListActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SiteCategoryListActivity.java:67)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.support.v4.app.Watson.onCreatePanelMenu(Watson.java:44)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:560)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:64)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:164)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:851)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:258)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
09-30 17:39:06.992: W/MenuInflater(17111):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Class names are case sensitive - you need to use

```
android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
```

Note the lack of capital letters in `actionbarsherlock`.

Comment: I made the change, but now I'm getting the same can not instantiate class on com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView.  I've read through the other stackoverflow posts and tried modified the theme xml class in ActionBarSherlock.  Not sure what to try next.